# Who is in fact localParticipantIdentifier?

Tags: ios, ios-messages-extension, msmessage, msmessagetemplatelayout

I am creating this interactive messages app.

Every time I compose a message and send to the other side and use this command:

```
  [messageTemplateLayout setSubcaption:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",self.activeConversation.localParticipantIdentifier.UUIDString]];
```

I get the other side's name.

For example, if I´m on the simulator using `Kate` and I send a message to `John Appleseed`, the message is sent with the subcaption `John Appleseed` and vice-versa. In other words: `John Appleseed` receives a message with his own name and this is true for `Kate` too.

Shouldn't the `localParticipantIdentifier` be who is sending the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have come across a known issue with the iPhone simulator. There is an open radar for this issue that says that it works correctly on an actual device but not on the simulator. See this [link](http://www.openradar.me/26850679).

Comment: so, it is impossible to identify the local or the remote users correctly?

Comment: It seems that this bug occurs only on the simulator. From the linked open radar report it seems you can refer to the senderParticipantIdentifier to get the person who is sending the message.

Comment: ok, but it is very risk to develop something without testing... OK, I can test on the device if it appear correct, but I cannot have the messages back and forth to test the whole thing... anyway, thanks"

Comment: Oh great, I have tested this on device, sending a message to a friend of mine... I appear on the caption as "mobile user"... I love these half cooked device Apple push to us.